# Print list of values from various arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to gather values from my API to input them into a graph. With that, I am looking to get an array of just the value 'date'. I have queried through the data to get the following printed:

[image]

That is through the following code:

```
return {
    props: {
      data: data
    }
  }

  console.log([[props][0]['data']])
```

How do I simply get the 336 'date' values in an array? For example, [20210112, 20210111, 20210110...] I could not find any documentation to help with this issue, and I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `map` the data items and inside the callback, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `date` field and return its value.

```js
const data = [
  { date: 20210101 }, { date: 20210102 }, { date: 20210103 },
  { date: 20210104 }, { date: 20210104 }, { date: 20210105 }
];

const datesOnly = data.map(({ date }) => date);

console.log(datesOnly);
```

Destructuring can be simplified as:

```js
const item = { date: 20210101 };

// Left-hand of assignment: Variables that match the field to be extracted
const { date } = item;

console.log(date);
```

The variables can also be renamed:

```js
const item = { date: 20210101 };

const { date: myDate } = item;

console.log(myDate);
```

---

### Update

If you want multiple field, you can `map` a new object.

```js
const data = [
  { date: 20210101, eg: 1 }, { date: 20210102, eg: 2 }, { date: 20210103, eg: 3 },
  { date: 20210104, eg: 4 }, { date: 20210104, eg: 5 }, { date: 20210105, eg: 6 }
];

const datesEgsOnly = data.map(({ date }) => date);
const egsOnly = data.map(({ eg }) => eg);
const datesAndEgsOnly = data.map(({ date, eg }) => ({ date, eg }));

console.log(datesEgsOnly);
console.log(egsOnly);
console.log(datesAndEgsOnly);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Follow up question: Can you edit the answer to fetch multiple values, for example exporting 'dates' and 'eg'?

Comment: @Mallard what is `eg`?

Comment: I just mean eg as another value... I'm attempting to gathering both dates and 'eg' but since I can only return one value I do not know how to get both.

Comment: @Mallard in a flat list, or new objects? I added an example at the bottom of latter.